# How to use the rand function?

Tags: image-processing

I took DFT of an image and then magnitude of DFT using the abs function.
Now I am supposed to corrupt the magnitude of the image with interval `[o,o.o1 * max(image)]`
used the rand function. But it gives error that input argument must be scalar.
I tried `r=rand(0,0.01 *max(abs(F)));`
Is that correct?

Comment: [Insert expletive here] What programming language are you using?

Comment: looks like PHP, OP you really need to tag it appropriately!

Answer (score 0):

What language?

---

The "max" function in most languages gives the largest value out of two arguments, while you pass only one argument to it, so it returns nothing or error (definitely not scalar). Remove the "max" function, you don't need it if you have only one number.